# TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, jestjs, serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

I a persistent error while using `serverless` framework with `serverless-offline` and `jest` unit testing module.

I am trying to test my serverless function (lambda) using `serverless-jest-plugin` which is supposed to integrate `jest` on `serverless`. Following is my `jest` configuration in my `serverless.yml`:

```
custom:
 default:
  stage: dev
 table:
  dictionary: Dictionary
  rules: Rules
 jest:
  verbose: true
  testResultsProcessor: jest-junit
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/node_modules", "<rootDir>/lib"]
  roots: ["<rootDir>/tests"]
  testEnvironment: node
plugins:
   - serverless-jest-plugin
   - serverless-dynamodb-local
   - serverless-offline
```

I have a lambda function which uses dynamoDB to get some data etc.

Whenever I use `sls invoke test` I have the following:

```
$ sls invoke test
 FAIL  tests/file.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

  at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
  at Object.relative (path.js:1226:5)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.386s
Ran all test suites.
```

I'm running the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.1.1",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.188.0",
    "notevil": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^22.2.1",
    "jest-junit": "^3.5.0",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.27",
    "serverless-jest-plugin": "^0.1.6",
    "serverless-offline": "^3.16.0"
  }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: As a workaround I've used `serverless-jest-plugin` inside each one of my test files then wrap my lambda functions with `lambdaWrapper`. then call test files with `npm test`.

Comment: Here's an example: 
```javascript
const jestPlugin = require('serverless-jest-plugin');
const lambdaWrapper = jestPlugin.lambdaWrapper;
const myFunction = require('/../services/function1');
const wrappedFunction = lambdaWrapper.wrap(myFunction, {
  region: 'your_region', 
  handler: 'handler'
});
// Here you should prepare your lambda event then call it
wrappedFunction.run(event, (err, response) => { ... });
```